# Mysql update same table column by condition and group by column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-functions

Here is Mysql table I want to set version column as below.there are millions of records need to be updated for version column

```
File_id |file_name |  type  | flag     | original_file_id  |  version

   1    |abc.jpg   | FILE   | RENAMED  |      1            |   1 
   3    |folder1   | FOLDER | RENAMED  |      3            |  null
   5    |folder1   | FOLDER | null     |      3            |  null
   7    |abc1.jpg  | FILE   | null     |      1            |   2 
   9    |abc1.jpg  | FILE   | DELETED  |      1            |   2 
   11   |abc.jpg   | FILE   | MOVED    |      1            |   3 
   13   |abc.jpg   | FILE   | null     |      1            |   4 
   15   |xyz.jpg   | FILE   | null     |      6            |   1 
   17   |xyz.jpg   | FILE   | DELETED  |      6            |   1 
   19   |xyz.jpg   | FILE   | null     |      6            |   2
```

I want to set version like set as above.For 1st file where file_id=original_file_id then version=1.if flag is DELETED then set previous version like version 2.for other RENAMED,MOVED increment version.But it should update only for files not for folder.

Comment: What is the primary key column in your table?

Comment: @JimMacaulay sorry I have updated my question  file_id is primary key

Comment: @GordonLinoff No,revision is decide on flag and original_file_id. And version is not same as original_file_id check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
update files
join 
( select f1.file_id, 
    count(f2.file_id) + count(distinct forg.file_id) as version
  from files f1
  left outer join files forg
  on f1.original_file_id = forg.file_id
    and f1.original_file_id = forg.original_file_id
    and forg.flag = 'DELETED'
  left outer join files f2
  on f1.original_file_id = f2.original_file_id
    and f1.file_id >= f2.file_id 
    and coalesce(f2.flag,'') <> 'DELETED'
    and coalesce(f2.type,'') <> 'FOLDER'
  where coalesce(f1.type,'') <> 'FOLDER'
  group by f1.file_id
) fileversions
on fileversions.file_id = files.file_id
set files.version = fileversions.version
where coalesce(files.type, '') <> 'FOLDER';
```

It will increase the version in each `original_file_id`-group unless it has a `flag = 'Deleted'`. All rows with `type = 'Folder'` are ignored and not updated.

The first file with `file_id = original_file_id` will get version 1, even if it has `flag = 'deleted'`, in that case, the next not deleted file will get version 2.

The query will not check if your data is corrupted, e.g. if the file with `file_id = original_file_id` exists or if there are files that have an id with `file_id < original_file_id`.

You need an index `original_file_id` (or `original_file_id, file_id`) if you want it to finish in a reasonable time.

Comment: Thanks for help.But I have some doubts.1) (If the first file of a group has that flag, it's version is set 0) this should not expected because first file always get version 1 not anything else. 2)if somewhere orginal file record is corrupted then how it can handle? like originalfileid 50 and that group have 3 files with fileid 51,52,53 and original file id is 50 but file with originalfileid and fileid 50 is corrupted.

Comment: 1) what should happen if first entry is deleted? You said a "deleted" file should get "version before", which doesnt exist 2) I don't understand what you mean by that, can you give an example and the result you would like to have then? But generally: if your data is not clean, you cannot expect a clean result. Do you mean something like `original_file_id = 6`? Even if `file_id = 6` does not exist, my query will give you exactly the output in your question for this case (version 1 for `file_id = 15`).

Comment: forget about 2nd condition of corrupted data.but the 1st condition must be there which is files which have fileid=originalfileid which have version always 1.for example,in my example table files with file id 1 and 15 are 1st file with original file id is always 1 irrespective of flag.for whatever are after that need to consider flag.

Comment: everything is perfect except this condition version must start with 1.it should not be zero.

Comment: So assume in your example data, file_id's 1, 7 and 9 would have the flag "deleted", the versions for file_ids 1, 7, 9, and 11 would be: 1, 1, 1, 2? Correct?

Comment: @ Solarflare u need to consider revision for 1st file is always 1 irrespective of flag ,And after that other files with that original file id  if flag is deleted it takes previous version  and if flag is other than than deleted it need to increment version.

Comment: @techsavvy I added a condition for that. The first file will now always be version 1, even if it is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
UPDATE FILES
SET version = CASE
WHEN original_file_id = File_id THEN File_id
WHEN flag = 'DELETED' THEN (SELECT F1.version-F2.version FROM FILES F1, FILES t2 WHERE F1.File_id = F2.File_id -1)
WHEN flag = 'RENAMED' THEN ((SELECT F1.version-F2.version FROM FILES F1, FILES t2 WHERE F1.File_id = F2.File_id -1)+1)
WHEN flag = 'MOVED' THEN ((SELECT F1.version-F2.version FROM FILES F1, FILES t2 WHERE F1.File_id = F2.File_id -1)+1);
```

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: I get it but I updated my question again by changes in table columns added type column please check this now.I need to update only for files not for folders.So for file_id its not always increment by 1.

Comment: After each where condition provide **AND F1.type='FILE' **. Will you be able to do it? or you need entire query again?

Comment: Thats fine I can add condition where type="FILE" but F1.File_id = F2.File_id -1 is this works? because you can not ensure next file_id.suppose abc.jpg file_id 3 then next file_id can be anything like 60.so for this WHERE F1.File_id = F2.File_id -1 what can I do?

Comment: Your query relies on consecutive file_ids per group (no gaps, and no other filegroups in between). I don't think that is a valid assumption.

Comment: On what basis you want to populate original_file_id ?

Comment: file_id incremented by 2 but 1 file abc with file_id 6 inserted and in between 20 folders and 25 files inserted it means 20*2=40 and 25*2=50 so file_id incresed by 90.And then file which have original_file_id 6 file get renamed the that file_id is 96

Comment: Modify the query and apply the same logic as you required. If you think logically and do it, you will gain good knowledge